# Singleton pattern vs using an object once?

Tags: java, singleton

Let's say I want to use a `Car` object in my code, when should I use singleton pattern vs just having the object called once? (After some reading, people say it's easy to misuse singleton pattern, so I want to make sure i'm not misusing it.)

Why can't I just create an instance of an object and use it only once? Am I missing anything?

e.g.

```
Car car1 = new Car();
```

Like in this case. I just create an instance of `Car`, `car1`, and I'm done. no need to create another `CarSingleton` object to keep track of it?

Comment: Yes, don't use the singleton antipattern (or any bizarre variant on it).

Comment: yeah i'm reading all these different sites/threads and it's very controversial. people either really love them or really hate them

Comment: This is too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is aimed at avoiding open-ended long-winded discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton means only one instance will be there for jvm. There are use cases where it is very useful like Java `Runtime` class.. So it completely depends upon your use case.

Comment: basically if i'm a noob, not writing a base class, i should stay away from singleton pattern?

Comment: If you don't want to have only one instance for jvm, no need to use Singleton pattern. In your case I don't think you need it.

Comment: let's say currently i have a `List` of objects created by a static method that i pass around to parse/check, would it make sense to make the `List` into one singleton object instead, so i wouldn't have to pass around this list of objects? unless i'm missing something